# Stop Minimization after condition

Tags: mathematical-optimization, evaluation

I want to interrupt the optimization of a function when a particular condition is satisfied. Here I provide a test function.

```
Catch[NMinimize[x^6 + y^4 - 1, {x, y}, Method -> {"RandomSearch"} , 
EvaluationMonitor :> If[x^6 + y^4 - 1 < -0.95, Throw[x]]]]
```

I would expect the result to be `x=...`, but Mathematica seems not to evaluate the code and returns just

```
NMinimize[-1 + x^6 + y^4, {x, y}, Method -> {"RandomSearch"}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> If[x^6 + y^4 - 1 < -0.95, Throw[x]]]
```

I am new on Mathematica, so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I always have trouble with this - I think it's a bug. You could try this instead: `Catch[FindMinimum[X = x; z = x^6 + y^4 - 1, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, EvaluationMonitor :> If[z < -0.95, Throw[X]]]]` NMinimize doesn't work as well with conditions in the EvaluationMonitor for some reason - probably evaluation order or some interaction with the Method.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, in my actual problem (which involves many variables) I need to find the global minimum of a function, while FindMinimum only gives a local one. I want to use EvaluationMonitor in case the algorithm does not converge, so that I can at least find a good result. But even if you know of any other function doing the same, it would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You need to throw and catch with tags here since `NMinimize` has other throws and catches internally:

```
Catch[NMinimize[x^6 + y^4 - 1, {x, y}, Method -> {"RandomSearch"}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> 
   If[x^6 + y^4 - 1 < -0.95, Throw[x, "stop"]]], "stop"]
```

On a related note: just make it a habit to always use tags when throwing. It's just good practise.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. And thanks also for the suggestion!